# Input multiple dataset for training on tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have dataset `trainX` and `trainZ` which leads to `trainY`(answer)

For example

```
trainX
[[4,3,5,2],[4,5,3,4],[2,3,5,4]]    

trainZ
[[1,2,4,2],[2,1,3,2],[3,5,4,2]]

trainY (answer)
[[0],[1],[1]]
```

For now, I successfully made model to input only `trainX` [3x4] and get `trainY` [1x3] as answer

```
n_hidden = 50

w_h = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4,n_hidden],stddev=0.001))
b_h = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hidden]))

w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden,1],stddev=0.001)) 
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,4]) 
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,1])

h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x,w_h) + b_h)
y = tf.matmul(h,w) + b

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y,labels=t))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.to_float(tf.greater(y,0.5)),t)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for epoch in range(trainingNum):
    sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={
        x: trainX,
        t: trainY
    })
    if epoch % 1000  == 0:
        trainAcc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: trainX, t: trainY})
```

Now I would like to input `trainZ` too.

I have two ideas,

1) make another model for trainZ and concatte result somehow???

2) simple `concat(trainX,trainZ)` dataframe??

Which idea is correct??

I am afraid idea 2 is somewhat too bulky though....

I think this is the second step for beginners after understanding simple deep-learning structure.

Is there any good reference or web site??

Comment: What is trainZ exactly ? More samples, more features for the same samples as X, or something else ? If it's other features, do you want to treat them like trainX, or do you have reasons to treat them differently ?

Comment: put trainZ in your feed_dict?

Comment: For example trainX is the stock price for each companys on one  day , and `trainZ` is traded Volume for each companyes on one day. trainX and trainY is also related with `trainY`, however trainX and trainZ are apparently defferent type of values.